# Loop through injected objects in a factory

Tags: angularjs

In angualrjs  how do i iterate through the injected objects of a factory.

```
angular.module('SomeModule', ['AnotherModule'])

.factory('SomeFactory', [
    'Value1', 
    'Value2', 
    'Value3', 
    'Value4', 
    function(){

        // how to loop through the injected values, Value1, Value2, Value3 etc..
        return {


        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I JavaScript, the arguments of a function are stored in the `arguments` array-like variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
}
```